# DotNet Pack Not Doing Anything

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I am trying to create a nuget package for my web application but it is not producing any .nupkg outputs. I am using Visual Studio 2017 15.3.0.

To create the project I do the following:

- File - New - Project,
- Visual C# - Web,
- Asp.Net Core Web Application,
- Web Application

Then I go to a command prompt in the directory with the csproj file in and type:
"Dotnet Pack"

I get only the following output:

> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.409.57025 for .NET Core
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

But no nuget packages are created. I am expecting something like:

Producing Nuget Package "App.1.0.0" for App

Do I need to do anything else eg to the csproj file ?

Comment: So you expect to create a nuget package from a website? not saying it's right or wrong, but what would you expect from that package?

Comment: Its so that I can produce a Nuget package in TeamCity that can be deployed by Octopus Deploy. Correct me if there is a better way.

Comment: Octopus Deploy suggests to use `dotnet publish` to generate a published output and then use `octo pack` on that output. Please consult [its documentation](https://octopus.com/docs/guides/deploying-asp.net-core-web-applications).

Comment: I am in the same situation as wanting to deploy from vsts builds into managed openshift platform. The managed platform wants to choose the Docker runtime so that a dozen teams don't have to change their Docker files for security patches. Not having a way to deploy an asp.net core website as a package means that I will need to ship zip files around

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Web applications are not packable by default. To change this, modify your csproj file to include this property:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Note that as of now (2017) there isn't a good story for "library web projects" or web project packages that work for all scenarios you would want to use a NuGet package for. But this property will at least unblock producing a package.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand your comment though. I'm doing this so that I can produce a Nuget package in TeamCity that can be deployed by Octopus Deploy. Correct me if there is a better way of deploying from Octopus via TeamCity.

Comment: https://octopus.com/docs/guides/deploying-asp.net-core-web-applications

Comment: Considuer using the output of `dotnet publish` to publish an app to get the correct layout.

Comment: This also applies to projects that VS thinks are test projects.

Comment: Also applies to Worker projects (`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">`)

Comment: This also only works if you have the <IsPackable>true</IsPackable> element in under its own PropertyGroup. I tried adding it to the main PropertyGroup and it didnt work. go figure

Comment: Ran into this with `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` project after adding reference to `MSTest` (built and generated nugets previously). Adding the property helped with this ‍♂️. Ah, apparently Douglas Gaskell's comment is about this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with VS2022, looked at the documentation and noticed they "silently deprecated" the command.

You now should add the following in your .csproj file:

```xml
<Target Name="CopyPackage" AfterTargets="Pack">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutputPath)..\$(PackageId).$(PackageVersion).nupkg"  DestinationFolder="D:\NuGet" />
</Target>
```

You then generate a package and copy it to the "right" folder by calling

```
dotnet msbuild -t:pack -property:Configuration=Release "ProjectFile.csproj"
```

Have a look at [the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#packing-using-a-nuspec), the title is a bit confusing but there seemed to have been a change after With MSBuild 15.1+